# What can I do to make this code shorter to accommodate the line limit

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

So I have an assignment to make a game, and I made it but it is just over the line limit. I tried deleting as many blank lines and other things as much as possible without breaking the syntax rules as well as keeping proper form (curly brackets). The game is that the computer generates 4 numbers (1-10) and gets a final number that is either added or subtracted from the 4 numbers (random 1 or 2) and the person needs to figure out whether to add or minus each number. The code has no problem, just need to make a little shorter. (A few lines maybe?)

Here is my code:

```
//ROHAN DATTA (ICS2O8-C) - Magic Operations Game
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MagicNumberOperations {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num1, num2, num3, num4, operation, finalAns = 0;
        String equation = "", userAns, playAgain;
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("You are now playing: MAGIC NUMBER OPERATIONS");
        System.out.println("In this game, the computer generates 4 random numbers (1-10), \nand you must choose which operation (+ or -) to use with each number in order to get the final result (Determined by the computer!)");
        do {
            num1 = (int)(Math.random()*(10-1+1)+1);     //Randomly generating 4 numbers
            num2 = (int)(Math.random()*(10-1+1)+1);
            num3 = (int)(Math.random()*(10-1+1)+1);
            num4 = (int)(Math.random()*(10-1+1)+1);
            operation = (int)(Math.random()*(2-1+1)+1);
            if (operation == 1) {               //Determining whether or not to add or subtract
                equation = num1 + "+" + num2;   //Making word equation to compare with user answer later
                finalAns = num1 + num2;         //Creating integer answer to create the final number
            }
            else if (operation == 2) {
                equation = num1 + "-" + num2;
                finalAns = num1 - num2;
            }
            operation = (int)(Math.random()*(2-1+1)+1);
            if (operation == 1) {
                equation += "+" + num3;
                finalAns += num3;
            }
            else if (operation == 2) {
                equation += "-" + num3;
                finalAns -= num3;
            }
            operation = (int)(Math.random()*(2-1+1)+1);
            if (operation == 1) {
                equation += "+" + num4;
                finalAns += num4;
            }
            else if (operation == 2) {
                equation += "-" + num4;
                finalAns -= num4;
            }
            System.out.println("\n\nHere are your 4 numbers: " + num1 + ", " + num2 + ", " + num3 + ", " + num4);       //Statements
            System.out.println("And here is what all the numbers together should be: " + finalAns);
            System.out.print("\nEnter the whole equation (NO SPACES): ");
            userAns = input.nextLine();
            if (!userAns.equals(equation)) {
                System.out.println("Incorrect!");
                System.out.println("The correct answer was: " + equation);
                break;                          //If answer is wrong, loop breaks, GAME OVER!
            } 
            System.out.print("Correct! \n\nWould you like to play again (y / n) ?");
            playAgain = input.nextLine();
        } while (!playAgain.equals("n"));
        input.close();
        System.out.println("\n\nGAME OVER!");
    }
}
```

Comment: `System.out.println("x")` followed by `System.out.println("y");`  can be replaced by `System.out.println("x\ny");`

Comment: `2-1+1 == 2`.  So why write `2-1+1`?

Answer (score 0):

Switch part of the codes to this:

```
baseNum = (int)(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
equation = baseNum + "";
finalAns = baseNum;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    num = (int)(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
    if (Math.random() * 2 < 1) {
        equation += "+" + num;
        finalAns += num;
    }
    else {
        equation += "-" + num;
        finalAns -= num;
    }
}
```

Comment: The first 3 lines can be further shortened to `equation = "" + (finalAns = (int)(Math.random() * 10 + 1));` and the ìf/else statement can be replaced by following 3 lines: `boolean r = Math.random() * 2 < 1;`, `equation += (r ? "+" : "-") + num;` and `finalAns += r ? num : -num;`.

Answer (score 0):

27 lines shorter:

```
//ROHAN DATTA (ICS2O8-C) - Magic Operations Game
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MagicNumberOperations {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("You are now playing: MAGIC NUMBER OPERATIONS");
        System.out.println("In this game, the computer generates 4 random numbers (1-10), \nand you must choose which operation (+ or -) to use with each number in order to get the final result (Determined by the computer!)");
        try (Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            do {
                int finalAns, num;
                String equation = "" + (finalAns = (int)(Math.random() * 10 + 1));
                System.out.print("\n\nHere are your 4 numbers: " + equation + ", "); // Statements
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    System.out.print((num = (int)(Math.random() * 10 + 1)) + (i < 2 ? ", " : "\n"));
                    boolean r = Math.random() * 2 < 1;
                    equation += (r ? "+" : "-") + num;
                    finalAns += r ? num : -num;
                }
                System.out.println("And here is what all the numbers together should be: " + finalAns);
                System.out.print("\nEnter the whole equation (NO SPACES): ");
                if (!input.nextLine().equals(equation)) {
                    System.out.println("Incorrect!");
                    System.out.println("The correct answer was: " + equation);
                    break; // If answer is wrong, loop breaks, GAME OVER!
                }
                System.out.print("Correct! \n\nWould you like to play again (y / n) ?");
            } while (!input.nextLine().equals("n"));
        }
        System.out.println("\n\nGAME OVER!");
    }
}
```